# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' creating txt file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert to .txt with html libraries to manipulate tables in pdf files. First i wanted to convert from pdf to txt but text was corrupted. This version outputs the way I want but only converts a single pdf in the file.

```
def findPdf():
    os.chdir(adres)
    for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
        tables = camelot.read_pdf(file)
        print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)
        print(tables[0].df)
        tables[0].to_html(file+".txt")

findPdf()
print("Process succesfull")

"My error" 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Hi kronos_58, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about this code. Is it working, or is it raising an exception? Can you show the alternative code that did something else (and explain exactly what different output you got)?

Comment: @Blckknght This code working just 1 pdf; however, I will read approximately 4000 pdf file. I want to put in loop but i cant.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace? Which line is it complaining about?